# Linux MS Teams preview + XMonad: Possible to have notifiactions float?

Tags: linux, microsoft-teams, xmonad

When running *Linux* Teams (preview) in XMonad all notifications that should normally showup as a little floating windows are integrated into the tiling and reorder the layout. This is a bit irritating and I wanted to ask weather there is a way to leave the Teams notifications floating.
I have some rules for applications to shopup as float:

```
myManageHookonly 
myManageHook = composeAll
     [                                                                                     
      resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore                                          
    , className =? "Galculator"     --> doFloat                                           
    , className =? "Steam"          --> doFloat                                           
    , className =? "Gimp"           --> doFloat                                           
    , resource  =? "gpicview"       --> doFloat                                           
    , className =? "MPlayer"        --> doFloat                                           
--  , className =? "VirtualBox"     --> doShift "6:vm"                                    
    , className =? "Xchat"          --> doShift "7:media"                                 
    , className =? "stalonetray"    --> doIgnore                                          
    , isFullscreen --> (doF W.focusDown <+> doFullFloat  )]
```

But I think these definitions affect all windows of a prog however the Teams app itself should be tiled while only the notifications should remain floating. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please post this [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)?

Comment: Use 'xprop' and look for the second string at WM_CLASS(STRING); if the notification windows are not named differently than the main window I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want. Maybe look how people handle gimp - I thought there was a layout for this in the contribs, but it seems I just saw it somewhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding this in the `composeAll`:

```
title =? "Microsoft Teams Notification" --> doSideFloat NE
```

This floats the notification in the top right, if you want it to appear somewhere else you can change `NE` to another direction.

Comment: doSideFloat is perfect, only one thing that nags: The focus is still taken by the popupfloat. So when it pops up and I'm in the middle of typing i loose focus. Is there maybe some addition to also leave focus in the current window?

Comment: I'm struggling with this also actually, I'll spend some time on it during the week and try to find a solution.

Comment: @KonradEisele this should stop the notifications gaining focus (it's working for me): `title =? "Microsoft Teams Notification" --> doSideFloat NE <+> doF focusDown`